# Add an additional control to a QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am using the Native file dialog, so there is no `layout()` but want to add an additional control to the dialog. The builtin Notepad application has a perfect example when they allow the user to select the desired encoding (see below, to the left of the "Save" button). Is it possible to add an additional control in Qt5 while still using the native dialog?

[image: Notepad file save dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Completely custom components are not available with native dialogs, filters can be controlled using [`QFileDialog::setNameFilters`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setNameFilters).

---

Qt's implementation of the native windows file dialog uses `ABI::Windows::Storage::Pickers`. You can check the implementation out [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/winrt/qwinrtfiledialoghelper.cpp.html#_ZN22QWinRTFileDialogHelper4showE6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEENS1_14WindowModalityEP7QWindow). Depending on the type of action you perform, the implementation uses `IFileOpenPicker`, `IFolderPicker` or `IFileSavePicker`.

If you want to manipulate the native dialog, this class would have to provide you with the option to do so. We can find the documentation for the `FileSavePicker` class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker?view=winrt-22000).
Going through the available options, you see that there is no interface to provide any specific custom UI element. If you would only need the filter, the QFileDialog provides you with the ability to set a filter using [`QFileDialog::setNameFilters`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#setNameFilters). If you need a completely custom control/functionality, you unfortunately have to provide your own QDialog.

Comment: That is what I feared. I really appreciate the detailed response. I plan to look at those links and see if there is some form of either custom code I can develop to accomplish my goal. If not, I hadn't thought about using filters in that manner, but it is a clever idea.

Comment: In theory there might be some way to subclass QFileDialog, and create a subclass of IFileSavePicker to get what you want - but that would be far more complex, and less readable, maintainable and portable than quickly creating a custom QDialog. It's all standard components anyway